# What is the correct way to upload files (image, video, audio, text, ...) to Cloudinary through a unique input with simple_form_for on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, file-type, simple-form-for

I am trying to implement a simple_form_for in my Rails app to attach many files on a ruby model. I want to upload several types of files (image, PDF, video, audio, .doc, ...). I use the ruby gem Cloudinary (with a free account) to store files in the cloud and Active Storage to link files with model instances. I use Rails 5.2.4.1 and Ruby 2.6.5 (see below my actual code)

Here is my model file:

```
class Substep < ApplicationRecord
 has_many_attached :documents
end
```

Strong params controller :

```
class SubstepsController < ApplicationController
 [...]
 private
 
 def substep_params
  params.require(:substep).permit(documents: [])
 end
end
```

Gemfile.rb :

```
gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.12.0'
gem 'simple_form'
```

My API key in .env file :

```
CLOUDINARY_URL=............
```

config/storage.yml :

```
cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
```

config/environments/development.rb :

```
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

app/views/substeps/_form.html.erb :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@substep) do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :documents, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }, label: "Select files" %>
 <%= f.submit "Send documents" %>
<% end %>
```

With this setup, I can manage images & PDF files easily.

However, I have read Cloudinary documentation (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration) and simple_form_for documentation (https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) to find the right way to manage also video, audio & text files with the same setup, but I have failed so far.

I've find in the Cloudinary documentation that we can use an option "**:resource_type => :auto**" to manage different types of files automatically. I have already tried several configurations which have given nothing.

```
<%= f.input :documents, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true, resource_type: :auto },... %>
<%= f.input :documents, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }, resource_type: :auto,... %>

<%= f.input :documents, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true, resource_type: "auto" },... %>
<%= f.input :documents, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }, resource_type: "auto",... %>

<%= simple_form_for(@substep, resource_type: :auto) do |f| %>
<%= simple_form_for(@substep), resource_type: :auto do |f| %>
```

I don't success to find how I can add this option to my simple_form_for input. Someone can help me, please ?

**EDIT 2020/07/13 :**
I have found the solution thanks to another Dev. Here is his answer below.

"Hi! I just had the same problem as you and **my solution was to update the cloudinary gem**. In previous versions the cloudinary gem had "image" as the default for resource_type and it looks like you can't pass that option through active storage to cloudinary.

As soon as I removed that '~> 1.12.0' from the Gemfile and updated the gem to version 1.16, it started accepting the upload of other media types.
Probably the resource_type option changed to auto somewhere along the line."

Comment: Is there a particular reason you wish to use simple_form_for and not just use form_with? This way you can have active storage handle the Cloudinary nuisances of each different file so it can be correctly categorized as an image, video, and raw file.

Comment: @DanielMendoza I use simple_form_for several times in my Rails app. Maybe it will be easier to use form_with to solve my problem. I didn't try it until now. But I have already setup my simple_form_for with many code from different sources (CSS, CKEditor, ...) and with Id & Class which are used by my Javascript. If I can keep my simple_form_for, I will have less changes to implement Cloudinary resources_type than if I modify all my form syntax code. Can you give me an example of form_with which include the resource_type, please ?